# Relation between horizontal and vertical velocity in parabolic path

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics

So our teacher asked this question:

> A particle P is travelling from A to B in a straight line with a velocity **v**.
> Another particle Q is also travelling from A to B but in a parabolic path with a horizontal velocity **v**.
>
> Which one takes lesser time?

He said Q takes lesser time and gave a logic that it's velocity increases till half its path and then decreases till it becomes **v** in the other half which I didn't quite get.

Can anyone explain this to me?

Comment: A few points in your question are missing. Anyway, I shall assume that the horizontal velocity you mention in the parabolic path is along the path AB, in that case since the velocity and displacement is the same in both the cases, the time taken will be the same. There is no mention of any external force such as gravity so I have assumed that both the velocities remain constant.

Comment: @Jennie sorry it is indeed along AB. Yes, that should be the case but our teacher told us that Q should take lesser time.

Comment: Horizontal velocity is not affected by parabolic motion, only vertical velocity is affected

Comment: @The Space Guy yes that's what I know...then how is time taken by P more than R?

Comment: As horizontal velocity remains constant there is no acceleration or deceleration in forward motion. So, as mentioned in your question 'velocity increases in first half and decreases in second half'...there is no such thing happening

Comment: Simple answer, as horizontal velocity in both the case is $v$, both will take same time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem statement seems to say that

- the linear path from A to B has speed $V_{lin}=v$.
- the parabolic path from A to B has $V_{par,x}=v$

Expanding on @JohnHunter's answer...

Since the time of flight from A to B is
$$t_{par}=\frac{\Delta x}{V_{par,x}} \quad= \frac{\Delta x}{(\ v\ )},$$
let's get corresponding equation for the linear path
by computing $V_{lin,x}$, the "x-component of $\vec V_{lin}$".

---

The angle of $\vec V_{lin}$ is gotten by $$\tan V_{lin,\theta}=\frac{\Delta y}{\Delta x}.$$
(Of course, this angle is not equal to the angle of the launch velocity for the parabolic path.)

So,
$$\cos V_{lin,\theta}=\frac{\Delta x}{\sqrt{ (\Delta x)^2+(\Delta y)^2 }}$$
Thus,
\begin{align}
V_{lin,x}&=V_{lin}\cos V_{lin,\theta}\\
&=V_{lin}\frac{\Delta x}{\sqrt{ (\Delta x)^2+(\Delta y)^2 }}\\
&=(\ v\ )\frac{\Delta x}{\sqrt{ (\Delta x)^2+(\Delta y)^2 }}\\
\end{align}
as expected.

---

So now, putting things together:
$$t_{par}=\frac{\Delta x}{V_{par,x}} \quad= \frac{\Delta x}{(\ v\ )},$$
and now
$$t_{lin}=\frac{\Delta x}{V_{lin,x}} \quad= \frac{\Delta x}{ (\ v\ )\frac{\Delta x}{\sqrt{ (\Delta x)^2+(\Delta y)^2 }} }=\frac{ \sqrt{ (\Delta x)^2+(\Delta y)^2 } }{(\ v\ )}.$$
With given conditions placed on their speeds (from above)

- the linear path from A to B has speed $V_{lin}=v$
- the parabolic path from A to B has $V_{par,x}=v$,

the time of flight for the linear path is longer
than that for the parabolic path
due to the $\Delta y$ term.

...in accord with @JohnHunter's answer.

Answer (score 1):

If A is the origin and B is (8,6) in meters, for example.

Then if the parabola is designed to go through A and B and the horizontal component is 2m/s, it takes 4 seconds to reach B, (blue and green line below).

For the straight line path, the distance between A and B is 10 units.  At 2m/s it takes 5 seconds.

The parabola is quicker unless AB is horizontal, then the times are the same.

[image]

Hopefully this explains what your teacher probably meant.